# Possible memory leak in a do-loop macro

Tags: vba, excel

I was reading about similar problems to the one I am having, and my guess is that I am having a 'memory leak'. I'm not sure exactly what that means, or how to correct.. but could you take a look at my code and help me optimize? `LastRow` is ~73000

```
start = Timer
Do Until Row > LastRow
DoEvents
    If Original.Cells(Row, 4) <> "" Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & Row & " out of " & LastRow & ": " & Format(Row / LastRow, "0.00%")
    'VLookUp method
'''''        Data.Cells(DataRow, 1) = Original.Cells(Row, 4)
'''''        Data.Cells(DataRow, 2) = Original.Cells(Row, 39)
'''''        Result = Evaluate("Vlookup('New Cost Data'!A" & DataRow & ",'PupFile Data'!B:D,3,false)")
'''''
'''''        If IsError(Result) = True Then
'''''            Data.Cells(DataRow, 3) = "No Old Cost"
'''''            DataRow = DataRow + 1
'''''        ElseIf Result = 0 Then
'''''            Data.Cells(DataRow, 3) = "No Old Cost"
'''''            DataRow = DataRow + 1
'''''        Else
'''''            Data.Cells(DataRow, 3) = Result
'''''            Data.Cells(DataRow, 4) = Format((Data.Cells(DataRow, 2) - Result) / Result, "0.00%")
'''''            DataRow = DataRow + 1
'''''        End If


    'Find() method
        Set RNGFound = Range(Pup.Cells(2, 2), Pup.Cells(Pup.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)).Find(Original.Cells(Row, 4))
        If Not RNGFound Is Nothing Then
           PupRow = Range(Pup.Cells(2, 2), Pup.Cells(Pup.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)).Find(Original.Cells(Row, 4), lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlRows, MatchCase:=True).Row
           Data.Cells(DataRow, 1) = Original.Cells(Row, 4)
           Data.Cells(DataRow, 2) = Original.Cells(Row, 39)
           Data.Cells(DataRow, 3) = Pup.Cells(PupRow, 4)
           Data.Cells(DataRow, 4) = (Data.Cells(DataRow, 2) - Data.Cells(DataRow, 3)) / Data.Cells(DataRow, 3)
        Else
            Data.Cells(DataRow, 1) = Original.Cells(Row, 4)
            Data.Cells(DataRow, 2) = Original.Cells(Row, 39)
            Data.Cells(DataRow, 3) = "No old Cost"
        End If
        DataRow = DataRow + 1
    End If
    Row = Row + 1
Loop
Application.StatusBar = False
finish = Timer - start
MsgBox finish
Stop
```

The Vlookup method took me about 500 seconds, but it slowed down considerably from the beginning. The find() method looked like it was taking much longer, so I am probably going with the vlookup, but what about the actual slowing down of the code? Is there something I need to change, or is slowing down over time just 'what happens'?

Comment: If it works, best to ask this in CodeReview.SE instead of here in Stack Overflow. A quick look though shows that you are using expensive operations in your loop. Also, `Data.Cells(DataRow, 1) = Original.Cells(Row, 4)` are a no-no. You should really use their `.Value` property instead. Lastly, don't use a Do-Loop when a For loop is more suited to your cause. `Row = Row + 1` is a rather expensive operation since you're modifying it inside your loop. Better to just have a for loop to iterate to your final value like `For Iter = 1 to LastRow` or somesuch.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the tips and idea for codereview.se!

Comment: Make sure you post your complete code as well. If I have time to review it, I'll answer this there.

Comment: Why are you running the `Find()` twice?  Would also be useful to add aproximate row counts - right now it's impossible to determine if your code is slow, really slow or as fast as would be expected for the amount of data you have.  Also try turning off screenupdating and setting claculation to manual before entering the loop.  That should give you some speed-up.

Comment: I run the `Find()` twice because sometimes what im looking for doesnt exist, so that's where the else statement takes over.

Comment: If `RNGFound` is Nothing then aren't you running the exact same search again ? (with a few more parameters, but those will persist if not specified *each time* you run `Find()`)

Comment: I run `find()` the second time if `RNGFound` is NOT nothing, but how would I store the row and column without running `find()` again? Setting the `find()` to a row errors out if I try to `find()` something that doesn't exist.

Comment: My bad - missed the `Not`...  In any case, you already have your `RNGFound` reference, which will be a single-cell Range object, which has `Row` and `Column` properties. So you can use `RNGFound.Row` in place of `PupRow` (and ditch the second `Find()` call)

Comment: what?! are you kidding me? you're fantastic! also, this is blatantly obvious after realizing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggested changes which should improve performance:

```
Dim tmp, rngFind As Range

Set rngFind = Pup.Range(Pup.Cells(2, 2), _
                        Pup.Cells(Pup.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Start = Timer
Do Until Row > LastRow

    tmp = Original.Cells(Row, 4)

    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then

        If Row Mod 100 = 0 Then
            'don't update status *every* row - will slow you down
            Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & Row & " out of " & _
                        LastRow & ": " & Format(Row / LastRow, "0.00%")
            DoEvents 'do this less frequently also...
        End If

        Set RNGFound = rngFind.Find(Original.Cells(Row, 4))
        With Data.Rows(Datarow)
            .Cells(1).Value = tmp
            .Cells(2).Value = Original.Cells(Row, 39)

            If Not RNGFound Is Nothing Then
                .Cells(3).Value = Pup.Cells(RNGFound.Row, 4)
                .Cells(4).Value = (.Cells(2) - .Cells(3)) / .Cells(3)
            Else
                .Cells(3) = "No old Cost"
            End If

        End With
        Datarow = Datarow + 1

    End If

    Row = Row + 1
Loop

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

Application.StatusBar = False
finish = Timer - Start
MsgBox finish
```

Comment: `With` statements, for some reason, have gone mostly unused in my all of my code writing. I use them for formatting, but that's it. Seeing this makes me realize how prevalent they can, and I guess, should be. Anyways, thanks for the answer and revision! I appreciate the feedback as always
!